# How To Scroll to the bottom of a TreeView in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, scrollbar, bottom-sheet

I've imitated a table widget using treeview in Tkinter. And add a scroll bar linked to it. The question is  as my data is add in the bottom by minute automatically, and I want the scroll at always scroll to the bottom. I know "text.see(END) "works perfectly in a text widget, but in my case, treeview widget didn't work. Thanks ahead!

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()
treedata = [('column 1', 'column 2'), ('column 1', 'column 2'), ('column 1',       'column 2'), ('column 1', 'column 2'), ('column 1', 'column 2'), ('column 1',    'column 2'), ('column 1', 'column 2'), ('column 1', 'column 2'), ('column 1', 'column 2'), ('column 1', 'column 2'), ('column 1', 'column 2'), ('column 1', 'column 2'), ('column 1', 'column 2'), ('column 1', 'column 2'), ('column 1', 'column 2'), ('column 1', 'column 222'), ('column 1', 'column 2')]
column_names = ("heading1", "heading2")

scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

tree = ttk.Treeview(root, columns = column_names, yscrollcommand =    scrollbar.set)

for x in treedata:
    tree.insert('', 'end', values =x)
for col in column_names: 
    tree.heading(col, text = col)
scrollbar.config(command=tree.yview)
tree.pack()
#tree.see(END)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could you possibly show us your code?

Comment: I know, but when I enter the code I can't submit. Can I send to your email?

Comment: Finally work out, the codes I've added.Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `tree.yview_moveto(1)` to display the bottom of the table. The `yview_moveto` method takes as argument the fraction of the total (scrollable) widget height that you want to be off-screen to the top.

So, `yview_moveto(0)` will display the top part of the table, `yview_moveto(1)` the bottom part and `yview_moveto(0.5)` will adjust the display so that the top half of the widget is hidden.